# Android-How Can I grant Runtime Permission with NO user interaction?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I made an app for testing various phone functions with no user interaction, but it was not working on some devices, even though it worked fine before.  My theory was that it needed runt-time permissions and I was right.  When I put the run-time permission in the activity, it works perfectly.  The problem is that it requests the permissions from the user and I can't have user interaction.  Is there a way to grant permissions to the activity without user interaction?

I will include an activity where I got the recorder activity to work, but is dependent on the user granting permission. Please help!!

```
    public static final int RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 3;



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                /*
         * API's to launch the application when the tablet is locked or
         * display is turned off
         */
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recorder);

        //Check to see if the device has a microphone
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean micPresent = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE);
        if (!micPresent) {
            Log.i(log_tag, "There is no microphone present in this device.");
            exit_function();
        } else {
            createTempFile(status_tag, "INPROGRESS");

            //Create the file to write the recording
            try {
                FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("audio_test.3gp", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(log_tag, "FAILED TO CREATE THE FILE OUTPUT STREAM");
                exit_function();
            }

//            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_REQUEST);

            //start_recording();
        }
    }




    //Start the Recording
    private void start_recording() {
        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.reset();
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;
        }
        //Setting for the Recorder
        try {
            Log.i(log_tag, "Setting the recorder");
            //This is the path that the file will be saved
            path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/audio_test.3gp";
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(path);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(log_tag, "Recording Settings Failed");
            exit_function();
        }
        //Prepare the Recorder
        try {
            Log.i(log_tag, "Preparing the Recorder");
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(log_tag, "Recording failed");
            exit_function();
        }

        //Start the Recorder
        try {
            Log.i(log_tag, "Starting the recorder");
            title_text = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView));
            title_text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            title_text.setText("RECORDING");
            recorder.start();

            //The recording lasts as long as he timer and then stops
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (recorder != null) {
                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.reset();
                        recorder.release();
                        recorder = null;
                    }
                    Log.e(log_tag, "First Delay");
                    exit_function();
                }
            }, timer);
            createTempFile(status_tag, "Complete");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(log_tag, "Recorder start failed");
            exit_function();
        }
    }
        @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case  RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_REQUEST:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    start_recording();
                } else {
                    onDestroy();
                }
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: **fortunately** you can't

Comment: If it would have to grant it automatically then whole process of runtime permission of no use. Keep your api level less than 23 to avoid runtime permissions

Comment: @Selvin seems like you intentionally forgot to put **un** before fortunately :P

Comment: As far as I understood you miss some new concepts of Android policy for permissions. From API level 23(Android 6.0) you Must give your users right to grant permission runtime, period. This us question of security.

Comment: Very true @Selvin, the problem is the device is forcing me to use these runtime permissions to run my application.

Comment: @PavneetSingh Nope, entirely intentional. Auto-granting permissions entirely defeats the purpose of runtime permissions brought in with Marshmallow.

Comment: @Vivek Mishra, how do I set the api less than 23?

Comment: change your sdk in app build.gradle

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is noted in the comments, this is not possible from ordinary Android apps, for blindingly obvious security reasons.

Frequently, for "testing various phone functions", we do not write an app, but a test suite using instrumentation testing. *There*, you could use UiAutomator to automate clicking on the permission dialog. However, this will only run as part of a test suite, from an Android SDK installation.

Alternatively, in your case, set your `targetSdkVersion` below 23, and you will not need to deal with runtime permissions. Eventually, something will force your hand to have a higher `targetSdkVersion` than that, but you might be able to "kick the can down the road" and deal with that challenge in the future.

Comment: This is the conclusion I just came to.  At least I know the problem for now.  I was beating my head against the wall trying to figure out why this would not work when it worked before.  Now I know the problem.  Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't what you want, but a user can technically grant permissions without interacting with **your app**.  In Android 6+ users can grant and deny individual permissions through the phone Settings -> Apps -> Permissions.  *Technically* this grants the permission without interacting with the app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this can't be done, because that would negate the purpose of permissions.

Perhaps if you had/wrote an app that could physically tap the permission box's allow button, ie. Something that can overlay other apps and interact with what's on the screen. But with something like that, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yea it is possible but its have a some limitations .

1) You have to use sdk 22 or below , if you use sdk above 22 than it will ask you 
     run time permission.

- go to app level gradle and put targetSdkVersion 22 .

i tried this method its works !

here sample project link :-https://github.com/kdblue/PermissionGranted